# How do I download the Crimson Map Pack if I own the War Games Map Pass?

Tags: halo-4

I purchased the War Games Map Pass, which says that it includes the three map packs, but now that the Crimson Map Pack has been released, I still do not have it, and the store item says not to purchase it again if I already own the map pass. I tried downloading the map pass again, but I still do not have the map pack. What do I have to do to get the map pack?

Comment: I am having the same problem, only I have the LE which gives me the pass for free. [This](http://www.oxm.co.uk/48327/halo-4-dlc-crimson-map-pack-released/) article seems to say that they are having problems with us not being recognized, they are working on the problem now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the [Xbox Live Status Page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live-status) the Xbox/MarketPlace team have acknowledged the issue and are working on it - a [recent](http://halo.bungie.org/news.html?item=38243) news post on Halo.Bungie.Org says:

> if your Xbox was on, shut it down and restart. If you head to the War Games Lobby, you should see the Crimson DLC list appearing, and selecting it will give you a chance to download the maps. (Louis Wu 17:26:01 UTC)

Try joining a Crimson DLC playlist and see if that prompts you.

Comment: OK, that worked. I tried that before but I hadn't restarted my Xbox.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the home page on halo 4 and go to xbox live market place.
Next there should be a few option one of which is the crimson map pack and under should be confirm purchase. you have to have the map pass for this to work
wait for it to download
then restart your xbox

Comment: Since I already managed to download the map pack I can't confirm that this works.