# Halo 4 War games Map pass problem

Tags: xbox-360, halo-4

I bought the **war games map pass**, then entered Halo 4 after it, I checked the Xbox Live Market Place trough Halo 4 and downloaded the 3 map packs, but still **I'm not seeing any of the playlist**. I saw a [question about  it from a few months ago](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95706/how-do-i-download-the-crimson-map-pack-if-i-own-the-war-games-map-pass) but still can't see the playlist. Any ideas of whats going on?

Comment: What playlists, exactly, are you not seeing? Have you tried playing with any of the DLC maps in a custom game?

Comment: I have seen in a few web pages that I'm supposed to see Crimson DLC playist and Majestic as well.

Comment: Also, are you sure that your map packs have finished downloading?

Comment: yup they did. There's nothing in the active download queue. Also I do see them in custom game, but the **Player do not have the recommended bla bla bla** warning keeps showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think those DLC-only playlists exist anymore.

Typically when Halo map packs are released, there will be a playlist that only contains the maps from that map pack. This way players can play the new maps easily, without having to also play the old maps they're tired of playing. However, after a while, the new maps will be folded into the rest of the play lists, and the DLC-only play lists will go away.

[Halo Waypoint](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/intel/playlists) has a list of the currently active play lists. I think most of them use any map packs that you've downloaded automatically, but I'm not positive on that.

If you want to check if Halo 4 is picking up your map packs (once they're fully downloaded), you should be able to start a private match and pick one of the downloaded maps.

If the download finishes while you're in the game, you'll need to restart the game for it to find the maps.

Comment: why do the **Player do not have the recommended bla bla bla** warning keeps showing.

Comment: @Guillelon Have you bought the Halo 4 Bullseye Pack or the Halo 4 Champions Bundle (which includes the Bullseye Pack)? They both include a couple of maps that aren't included with the War Games Map Pass.